# Safari Error kCFErrorDomainWinSock:10054

Tags: javascript, iis, safari

I have installed safari version 5.1.7 on windows and I have hosted js files on https windows server. The site is working fine but I am unable to view javascript files in Safari Browser.

[image]

Comment: Please check the console for any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved now. The issue is related with SSL Certificate, The TLS 1.0 was not enabled for SSL.

Comment: How was resolved? can you give more details for those we found this issue please?

Comment: IE Explorer -> Settings -> Internet Option -> Advanced Tab -> Select Use TLS 1.0

Comment: The question mentions safari and your answer mentions IE. Is this something new that I don't understand?

Comment: @Awani That setting you can apply through a different mode. You can also use a registry level setting to enable it. For more details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/solving-tls1-problem

Comment: I was already 'Using TLS 1.0' and I still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Just found option to enable TLS in safari . Click on the Setting icon -> Preference-> Advanced -> Proxies : Change Settings -> enable the TLS .