# Safari browser can't open my website

Tags: safari

[image: this is the message displaying when i try to open my website in safari.]

I have checked from another laptop too, I have cleared cache too. But the problem is still same. Thank you for your help. Here is the my website address

[My website](https://www.imajeet.com)

Comment: Just tested in my safari browser, works fine..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initial analysis suggests its might be due to installation issues on Windows OS as mentioned [here](https://www.solvusoft.com/en/errors/runtime-errors/apple-inc/safari/10054-safari-error-10054/) or you can refer to a **[similar StackOverflow thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41327458/safari-error-kcferrordomainwinsock10054)**.

Another forum suggests it might be an SSL issue, please refer to [this](https://devcentral.f5.com/questions/ssl-termination-broken-connection-safari-and-ie) link for more information on how to solve it.

Lastly, I did not check if the link is running in Safari or not because either it seems it is a problem with your installation or SSL configuration.

Can you specify which OS you are running?

Comment: @AJEETSINGH What?! Why are you using a browser that is almost six years old? That is insecure and it won't support many of todays websites.

Comment: @AJEETSINGH There is even a section about [unpatched security vulnerabilities in Windows Safari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_(web_browser)#Security_updates_for_Snow_Leopard_and_Windows_platforms) on Wikipedia. Do yourself and all web developers a favour and uninstall that thing immediately.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is working at my safari, so propably this is a problem on your side...

Try to:

- Change internet connection and try again
- Open page in private
- FlushDNS at you macbook

Bellow, I am sending code to execute at console to flush DNS

```
sudo dscacheutil -flushcache;sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

If will not help, maybe this is a problem with your router?