# Angular nebular web application does not load in the safari browser?

Tags: angular, safari, mobile-safari, nebular

I have developed a web application using angular and the [Nebular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Et48d.jpg) used as the UI Kit. Now the application does not load in the safari browser and it shows the following error message in the browser.

**Tested safari browser - 14.0.3**

Both of the mobile and mac version of safari does not load.

I checked Chrome, Firefox, and Edge browsers. Only the safari browser does not load.

This is safari on windows - safari version5.1.7

In Safari Windows version nothing loading. check the below screenshot.

[image: Safari waring message]

But in the safari mobile and mac versions. The splash screen is loading. nothing else.

[image: 14.0.3]

[image: Console]

I have no idea about this issue. Anyone can help?

Comment: Specify in which version of Safari you tested. Possibly related: [link](https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=160324#:~:text=Here%20are%20the%20causes%20of,or%20Safari%2Drelated%20program%20files.), [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41327458/safari-error-kcferrordomainwinsock10054/57050953), [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/220fad8f-149b-4f5a-8a8c-c7255419e1a5/kcferrordomainwinsock10054?forum=winservergen). This is possibly related to the device you're trying to open with, rather than the app itself.

Comment: @tao I updated the question. I check with safari mobile and mac version 14